Geospatial Analysis - Creating a weighted score considering 2 variables
I am a GIS Analyst working through an analysis and want calculate and assign a weighted score considering 2 main variables, One of which has a weighted calculation included.
I'm trying to rank properties so that if they are a high acreage-high priority property then they score the highest; opposite scores the lowest.
In short, I have data that classes priority based on 6 GIS environmental feature layers that overlap.---------
If  0 Layers overlap - Low Priority.----------
1-2 Layers Overlap - Medium Priority.----------
3-4 Layers Overlap - High Priority.------------
5-6 Layers Overlap - Very High Priority.------------
If an area extends past jurisdiction - Out Of County.
I used property data to calculate total acreage per property, and the % and Acreage breakdown of the priority classes above.
10 samples below (out of over 8000):Snip of data table
I want to give a weight to the priority classes. Let's say Medium is 1, High is 2, and Very High is 4. This makes each class twice as important as the class below, and half as important as the next class above.
In the final score, I want to consider the priority score and the acreage as equally important numbers.
Is it even possible to weigh these priority values even though they collectively add up to 100% ? Where I'm getting confused is when I try to apply weights to the values but they can't all be 100% at the same time because they are fractions of the total.
I also messed with creating a percentage score for the property Acreage that gives it a percentage based on its value in the range of acreages found.  Ex) 1708 Acres is the biggest property, so I divided every acreage by the max * 100.
What equation am I looking for and do I have enough to solve this. I've tried to lookup equations for weighted values and can't find much that seems applicable to my situation.
Let's say for Priority Score is P variable, Acreage is A, Score is S, and the priority scores are V for Very High, H for High, and M for Medium. My current equations look something like this.
S = ((P = (M∗1)+(H∗2)+(V∗4))+(8∗A))/16

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Sounds like you just need to calculate a score so create a function that will suit your needs. What is there to solve? For example, your function can take four acreage values (Low, Medium, High, Very high) as input and it will produce a score as output. It can be as simple as $S=8V+4H+2M+L$

You have done the GIS part already. The remaining work is not really geospatial. This part of problem statement is the key:

I'm trying to rank properties so that if they are a high acreage-high priority property then they score the highest; opposite scores the lowest.

You have a list of properties and two corresponding sets of score.
You want to define a new score that is high if both of the previously calculated scores are high. This implies a logical and operation: if the first score is high and the second score is high then the new score is high.
The numerical equivalent of the logical and operation is multiplication. Simply multiply the priority score into area.
Finally, if you want the newly calculated score to be a weight - i.e. if you want the sum of the newly calculated scores for all properties to be one, simply divide each newly calculated score by the sum of the newly calculated scores.
There is nothing wrong with having more than one way to distribute weights among a set of objects - in your case: properties.
